# user specific private content

Tags: plugins, php

I am creating a website for a courier at present.

One thing I am keen to include in the site is an area where clients can log and view their invoice history, update their information and view POD's (Proof of Delivery)

I have the first 2 areas covered, the part I am struggling with is the PODs.
this requires me to be able to upload user-specific private content.

for example, the user accesses their dashboard and selects POD History, it then takes them to a page that shows only their PODs, another customer could click the same link from their profile and again only see their own PODs...

Does anyone know of any ways of achieving this?

Comment: Hmm you can try taking advantage of [user IDs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/). Every user has one unique to them. Perhaps you can append the ID to the url that takes them to their history with a [query var](https://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/post/custom-query-string-vars-in-wordpress) and your logic will use that ID to pull specific history for that person. Sorry this isn't a "complete" answer - more of a suggestion, if it helps.

Comment: @RachieVee Thanks for that, sounds like a good suggestion, the only problem is, I am still learning lol. I will need to do some studying and see if/how this can be achieved :-)